# How to remap the search backwards evil-ex-search-previous command of evil?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, doom

I want to remap evil-ex-search-previous to some other key than `,`.
I tried

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "," 'evil-avy-goto-char-in-line)
(evil-define-key 'normal magit-mode-map "," 'evil-avy-goto-char-in-line)
(evil-define-key 'visual magit-mode-map "," 'evil-avy-goto-char-in-line)
```

However none of it worked. Using which key I see, that `,` is still bound to the old key.
How can I change this?

Comment: What in the first place would map it to `,`? That's certainly not the default. Generally, check out `evil-maps.el` for such questions.

Comment: I use doom-emacs, it may have something to do with this emacs configuration, but I don't know where I should look.

Comment: Yes, that is most certainly the problem. Please tag your question accordingly and consider asking on their Discord channel.

Answer (score 0):

I asked on discord channel and after some thinking the working solution specific to doom-emacs which I received is

```
(map!
 :nvm "," #'evil-avy-goto-char-in-line
 :desc "go to next char")
```